# Cannot change query name in Graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby

Alright guys am new to graphql and am having this weird behavior in my gatsby app. Am using strapi as backend and making a static query from gatsby.

```js
 const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      allStrapiCategory {
        edges {
          node {
            name
            strapiId
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

The above query works fine when query name is set to 'MyQuery'. But when I change query name to 'GetCategories' it gives me a error saying

> Error in function useStaticQuery in ./.cache/gatsby-browser-entry.js:77

> The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched. This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does not fix it, please open an issue in https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues

I like to set custom query name so it describes what it is fetching from backend.

Comment: What is unclear about: "please open an issue in ...." ? (Why did you not do it ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't stopped the development server when you changed the query name. In addition, the fact that is complaining about `/cache` folder is weird.

> Error in function useStaticQuery in
> ./.cache/gatsby-browser-entry.js:77

Try stopping the `gatsby develop` command, change the query name, clear the cache by running `gatsby clean` and run the `gatsby develop` again.